# I get a undefined curl_version() function in php

Tags: php, apache

I added Paypal Express checkout plugin to my website.
I get this error:

> 2019-07-23T15:45:32+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to undefined
>   function PayPal\Core\curl_version() in
>   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woo-paypal-express-checkout/includes/php-library/paypal-rest/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConfig.php:65

and this is the line

```
$curl = curl_version();
```

What can I do to resolve this probleme
I tried to install php-curl but I always got the same result
I used

`sudo apt-get install php5-curl
 sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Try install curl first `sudo apt-get install curl`, then reinstall php5-curl.

Comment: Try changing the line to `$curl = \curl_version();` and see if that helps

Comment: Is cURL installed or not? Have you looked at your `phpinfo` output? Not a `namespace` issue or something?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are missing the PHP CURL extension.  This is usually bundled as a separate package. If you are using Ubuntu, `apt-get install php-curl` (or `php7.2-curl`) will install the missing dependency.  You may need to enable the module after installing it using `phpenmod curl`.  If you are using another Linux distribution, please consult the appropriate distribution documentation for installing PHP modules.

Comment: if I use phpenmod curl I get this error "root@vps43313585:~# Module curl ini file doesn't exist under" /etc/php/7.0/mods-available

Comment: Did you install php-curl?  It looks like you are using a fairly old version of php.  Did an upgrade not go correctly?  Version 7.2 Is available with 18.04 LTS

Comment: Yes i install php-curl

Answer (score 0):

First, check your active PHP version, maybe there are multiple PHP versions installed on the server. In that case, you have to look for an active PHP version running on the server. Use `phpinfo();` to check PHP version. Then run the command as per your PHP version. In my case, it was PHP 7.3.

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install php7.3-curl
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```